# Daylight saving time from ZonedDateTime not working as expected

Tags: java, datetime, dst, java-time, zoneddatetime

I have the following function

```
public String getDateAndTimeInUserFormat(String value, DateTimeFormat inputFormat) {
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputFormat.getFormat()))
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(user().getTimezone()))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(user().getDateFormat() + " " + user().getTimeFormat()));
}
```

and the following test

```
@Test
public void getDateAndTimeInUserFormat() throws Exception {
    I18NService service = prepareForUserFormatCheck("####.000", "Brazil/Acre");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-05-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-05-2017 13:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-12-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-12-2017 13:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-01-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-01-2017 13:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-03-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-03-2017 13:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-07-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-07-2017 13:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-09-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-09-2017 13:52");
}
```

The test passes but it shouldn't. From my undersntading I should've received some results with a difference of one hour. Why do I have the same time for all these tests?

Comment: "It shouldn't" why? Which assertion is the incorrect one? Have you tried debugging this to see which part of that monstrous expression is at fault?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it seems that monstrous expression works fine. Please check the answer.

Comment: yes, I see. It looked fine as well (if we ignore that it's monstrous).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was the timezone. Daylight saving time does not apply to Brazil/Acre. Here is another test which proves it works fine.

```
  @Test
  public void getDateAndTimeInUserFormat() throws Exception {
    I18NService service = prepareForUserFormatCheck("####.000", "Brazil/East");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-01-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-01-2017 16:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-02-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-02-2017 16:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-03-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-03-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-04-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-04-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-05-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-05-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-06-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-06-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-07-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-07-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-08-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-08-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-09-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-09-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-10-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-10-2017 15:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-11-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-11-2017 16:52");
    assertEquals(service.getDateAndTimeInUserFormat("2017-12-06T20:52:52+0200"),"06-12-2017 16:52");
  }
```

Comment: Here's [the confirmation](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/porto-acre) that "Brazil/Acre" uses the same `UTC-5:00` offset all year-round since 2014. In fact, before 10th Nov 2013 it was using the `UTC-4:00`, and also didn't have daylight savings.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to check DST transition dates is to get the `ZoneRules` object from the `ZoneId`:

```
ZoneRules rules = ZoneId.of("Brazil/East").getRules();
```

Then you can check the list returned by `rules.getTransitions()`, to see all the dates when those changes occurred, and also the offset before and after the change.

Some zones don't have the transitions list, but have transition rules instead, which can be checked with `rules.getTransitionRules()`.